# How can I run Next.js with self hosted Node Js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, deployment

I'm new to `Next.js` and my goal is to achieve `SSR` (Server Side Rendering) with my `React` web app.
I would like to host it **on my own VPS**.

Everything is dandy running it locally but when I setup a CI pipeline things start to get confusing.

1. My code is pushed to git repo.
2. That triggers build pipeline with `next build` and produces an artifact that contains the content of `.next` directory aka build output.
3. The artifact is deployed to a directory on VPS (let's say under `/apps/myapp`)
4. Now how do I run this using `nodejs`? Running `next start` tells me that I'm missing `.next` directory.

This is the biggest thing that confuses. All docs say to deploy to the server and run `next build` and `next start` which implies that it will build the application on the production server which also implies that I need to deploy it with the source code? (which personally I find crazy).

Is that the way it is done or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I managed to do it but digging deeper into docs and trial and error:

I need to configure Next.js to standalone:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: 'standalone'
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Next in my pipeline I need to do the following:

```
# SM.Web is my root of the web project

yarn install

# overwrite your .env with environment specific stuff

echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=https://api.yourawesomeapp.com" >> src/SM.Web/.env

yarn build

cp -R src/SM.Web/public "src/SM.Web/.next/standalone/public"

cp -R src/SM.Web/.next/static" src/SM.Web/.next/standalone/.next/static"

# create artefact

zip src/SM.Web/.next/standalone SM.Web.zip
```

Once deployed:

`node server.js`

I described the entire process here:

https://dev.to/kedzior_io/deploy-self-hosted-nextjs-application-with-net-api-43p8